# How to set default data in input on click of dialog-box button?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

In a dropdown component which also has input box, a certain set of records is populated. A default value is set in that input on page load. Data in the input is changed on click of specific record. A dialog box also pops up on click of record, which has 'Cancel' and 'OK' buttons to send some respective output on its click. My intention is to set default value when clicked on Cancel button.

Please refer to the code below

```
const allList = [
    { id: "1", value: "Fruits" },
    { id: "2", value: "Vegetables" },
    { id: "3", value: "Grains" },
    { id: "4", value: "Milk" }
  ];

  const [itemList, setItemList] = useState(allList);
  const [popup, setPopup] = useState(false);
  const [cancel, setCancel] = useState(false);
  const itemChanged = (e) => {
    if (e.nativeEvent.inputType) {
      console.log("Data Changed from key press.....", e.currentTarget.value);
    } else {
      console.log("Data Changed from Drop down.....", e.currentTarget.value);
      setPopup(true);
    }
  };

  const handleOK = () => {
    console.log("OK");
    setPopup(false);
  };

  const handleCancel = () => {
    setCancel(true);
    setPopup(false);
  };

  //render grouped data
  return (
    <>
      <div className="col-md-5 profile-name">
        <div>
          <label className="form-label pt-2">Item ID</label>
        </div>
        <div className="select-with-search">
          <DataList
            defaultValue={allList[0].value}
            list="itemListOptions"
            id="itemList"
            placeholder="Search/select items"
            data={itemList}
            onSelectionChange={itemChanged}
          ></DataList>
        </div>
      </div>
      {popup === true ? (
        <Popup okbtnClick={handleOK} canclebtnclick={handleCancel} />
      ) : null}
    </>
  );
```

Popup file

```
<div className="modal-footer">
            <button
              type="button"
              className="btn btn-custom ok"
              data-bs-dismiss="modal"
              onClick={() => {
                props?.okbtnClick(true) ?? null;
              }}
            >
              OK
            </button>
            <button
              type="button"
              className="btn btn-custom cancel"
              data-bs-dismiss="modal"
              onClick={() => {
                props?.canclebtnclick(false) ?? null;
              }}
            >
              CANCEL
            </button>
</div>
```

As you can see from code above, the default value set is 'Fruits', but on click of 'Cancel' on popup box it doesn't update. What could be the best optimal solution?

Please also refer to Codesandbox link: https://codesandbox.io/s/clever-rumple-ig0wwj

Answer (score 0):

What you can do is to put default value in a state

```
const [defaultValue, setDefaultValue] = useState(allList[0].value)

const handleCancel = () => {
    setCancel(true);
    setPopup(false);
    setDefaultValue(otherValue)
  };
```

I also think it is a better practice to store more of your data in one state to avoid 3 setStates in one function like above and so 3 renders.

```
  const [state, setState] = useState({
    cancel: false,
    popup: false,
    defaultValue: allList[0].value
  })

  const handleCancel = () => {
    setState({
        ...state,
        cancel: true,
        popup: false,
        defaultValue: otherValue
    })
  };
```

Comment: can you update it in the sandbox?

Comment: its showing 'othervalue' undefined

Comment: Sorry but when you say you want to set default value when you click on cancel button, what value do you want ? I don't get what you mean sorry

Comment: I will explain you in short.... when any record is selected that gets displayed and popup appears, if clicked ok... it will disappear and that selected value is accepted but, when clicked on 'cancel', default value should update in the input box